# Bash permission denied in cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I have a directory:

```
drw-rwxrw-+ 1 username Domain Users 0 Feb 11 09:32 webapp
```

But when I try to enter this one I get

```
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/dp-project/.../web-app Permission denied
```

What's wrong? I setted all permissions to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you didn't "setted all permissions to all users". Execution permission is only set for group. try to `chmod a+x webapp`.

One othe thing first line `webapp` second line `web-app` that is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The plus (`+`) sign a the end of the permissions indicates that the file or directory has access control lists set. use:

```
getfacl /path/to/dir
```

to read all those acls. Most probably your user or groups access is prevented.